# Creating new folders for every download using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
for i in range(81,100):
try:
    result = "url.com/test?sid="+str(i)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/a[2]').click()
    time.sleep(3)
except Exception as e:
    print("Export as excel button not found. Error ",e)
    continue
```

I want to create new folders with 'sid' as its name which has the downloaded files for every .click() i.e everytime a file downloads, it gets saved into a new unique folder with it's 'sid'

Comment: use os lib, like https://thispointer.com/how-to-create-a-directory-in-python/ to create the folder.
You have to get the download link in a variable and then with requests downloads the file on the folder.

Comment: I do not have the direct download link since a user can download only when they're logged into the website.